# IndentationError: unexpected indent / python

Tags: python

```
    def createnewwallet(request):
data = {}
mykey = RSA.generate(1024)
public_key = mykey.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
private_key = mykey.exportKey('PEM')
wallet_id = hashlib.sha256(public_key).hexdigest()
data["public_key"] = public_key
data["private_key"] = private_key
data["wallet_id"] = wallet_id
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

when ı got go this code i got this alert ;

```
File "/opt/venv/cloudbank/cloudbank/views.py", line 41
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

anyone can help me thanks

Comment: read the error message. What could 'indention error' possibly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent it correctly!

```
def createnewwallet(request):
    data = {}
    mykey = RSA.generate(1024)
    public_key = mykey.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
    private_key = mykey.exportKey('PEM')
    wallet_id = hashlib.sha256(public_key).hexdigest()
    data["public_key"] = public_key
    data["private_key"] = private_key
    data["wallet_id"] = wallet_id
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```